# Dart object to native - UnimplementedError: structured clone of other type

Tags: dart, dart-html

Integrating a dart web app with the browser history, I want to push a dart object to the `window.history` stack.

Dart object.

```
class AppState {
  final int index;

  AppState(this.index){
  }
}
```

Api
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.15.0/dart-html/History/pushState.html

It works with e.g. a `Map toMap()` method, together with a matching factory constructor, but this is the brute force way. Just relying on the dart framework gives the stackdump below, which indicates that `AppState` misses some serialization method. Anyone know which?

```
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
UnimplementedError: structured clone of other type
#0      _StructuredClone.walk (file:///mnt/data/b/build/slave/dartium-lucid64-full-stable/build/src/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/conversions.dart:136)
#1      _StructuredClone.convertDartToNative_PrepareForStructuredClone (file:///mnt/data/b/build/slave/dartium-lucid64-full-stable/build/src/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/conversions.dart:151)
#2      convertDartToNative_PrepareForStructuredClone (file:///mnt/data/b/build/slave/dartium-lucid64-full-stable/build/src/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/conversions_dartium.dart:4)
#3      convertDartToNative_SerializedScriptValue (file:///mnt/data/b/build/slave/dartium-lucid64-full-stable/build/src/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/conversions.dart:33)
#4      History.pushState (dart:html:19793)
#5      AppHistoryCtrl.pushState (package:mintest/app_history_ctrl.dart:35:20)
```

Comment: I think you should report a bug in http://github.com/dart-lang/sdk

Comment: Ok. Wrote issue on this. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what's supposed to happen. In order to get into history, it gets serialized through the structured clone algorithm, which is specified. That doesn't know how to deal with arbitrary Dart objects. For example, if we push something into history that way, some JavaScript code might take it out, and that can't handle arbitrary Dart objects. So yes, it needs to be converted into a Map, or some other structure that the structured clone algorithm understands.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was concerned if the solution with a 'toMap()' method was overriding serialization functionality already existing in the Dart framework.